# How can I draw a polygon with a fixed area in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, area

Is there a way to draw a polygon with a fixed area in ArcMap?  For example, I'm trying to create a 40,000 foot boundary around a feature, but the boundary does not have to be any specific length or width.

Comment: Theoretically, aren't there an infinite number of shapes you could use? It might be best to chose the shape that makes the most sense, then go from there.

Comment: There are an infinite number of  ways to accomplish this, with just a rectangular shape. Adding in additional regular and non-regular shapes doesn't make the problem easier.  Please **edit** the question to clarify further constraints and specify a development language.  Eventually, you'll need to attempt some code.

Comment: Did you mean a 40,000 foot perimeter?

Comment: 40,000 SF, sorry.  It's the infinite number of shapes I'm trying to play with.  It's crazy time consuming to draw a shape calculate the area then edit the shape until the area matches my requirement.  I'm fine adding code or even creating a custom tool, I'm just not seeing the functionality in Arc, I was hoping someone smarter could point out a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate a square that meets your perimeter length or area requirement, then create a circle buffer where buffer distance = len/2
Convert the circle to envelope and that will create the square.

In this case your square will be 200 ft on each side

1. If your features are poly or line geometry then convert features to point
2. Create a 100 ft buffer from each feature.
3. Input your newly created buffers into the Feature Envelope to Polygon tool